# How do you make a sound file play automatically thought an iOS app and loop using Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio

I am making a game for iPhone using objective-c. I have the music I want to play in a file in the project. I need to know how to make it begin playing when the app launches, and loop at the end. Does anyone know how to do this? Code examples would be great! Thanks.

Comment: you probably want to show something you tried already. Thats the way SO works mostly. Just saying 'give me code for this and that' seldom works

Comment: I have looked around and nothing works, I can't figure this out and I don't have any code to show

Answer (score 2):

you can use AVAudioPlayer in App Delegate.

First in your App Delegate .h file add these lines:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

and these one:

```
AVAudioPlayer *musicPlayer;
```

In your .m file add this method:

```
- (void)playMusic {

    NSString *musicPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"phone_loop" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *musicURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:musicPath];

    musicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicURL error:nil];
    [musicPlayer setNumberOfLoops:-1];   // Negative number means loop forever

    [musicPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [musicPlayer play];
}
```

Finally call it in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  ...
  [self playMusic];
  ...
}
```

If you want to stop the music just:

```
[musicPlayer stop];
```

Aditionally you can check the Apple Documentation for AVAudioPlayer delegate for Handling Audio Interruptions http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html

PS: Remember to import the AVFoundation Framework to your project.

Comment: -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter

Comment: You should use [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:musicPath] because  initFileURLWithPath: is an instance method, not a class method, so you have to create an instance of the class first with alloc. ;)

Comment: Are you using this line: NSURL *musicURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:musicPath];?

Comment: no I'm doing: `NSURL *musicURL =  [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:musicPath];`

Comment: `NSString *musicPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Payphone" ofType:@"m4a"];
    NSURL *musicURL =  [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:musicPath];
    
    musicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicURL error:nil];
    [musicPlayer setNumberOfLoops:-1];   // Negative number means loop forever
    
    [musicPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [musicPlayer play];`

Comment: Yes, but I'm sure that you are getting NSString *musicPath = nil. Make sure that you added the file (sound) to your project ;)

Comment: okkay so I switched to a .mp3 file, and now it doesnt have the error anymore, but i dont hear anything

Comment: `- (void)playMusic
{
    
    NSString *musicPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"The History of the World" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *musicURL =  [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:musicPath];
    
    musicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicURL error:nil];
    [musicPlayer setNumberOfLoops:-1];   // Negative number means loop forever
    
    [musicPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [musicPlayer play];
    NSLog(@"play");
}`

Comment: i know the method is being called because play is logged, so is there a certin place the file needs to go in the project or something?

Comment: wait it tried it on the simulator and it worked, so is the volume need to be set or something ?

Comment: any ideas as to why it isnt wokring on the phone?

Comment: Try to restart the device and check. sometimes restarting the device it works. Otherwise then you can start debugging. I suggest to debug this line if isn't nil in the device: NSString *musicPath = ...

Answer (score 1):

First import AVFoundation Framework to your project. Then insert the music file into your project.

declare

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

And then

```
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
NSURL *file = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"soundName" ofType:@"mp3"]];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file error:nil];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1; // Infinite loops
    [audioPlayer setVolume:1.0];
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [audioPlayer start]
```

You can stop the sound before application goes to backgound by using

```
    [audioPlayer stop];
```

Comment: Would this goes in the app delegate?

Comment: It is possible. Generally it is better to avoid using the app delegate for such code but you can do it.

Comment: - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"play");
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
    NSURL *file = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Payphone" ofType:@"m4a"]];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file error:nil];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1; // Infinite loops
    [audioPlayer setVolume:1.0];
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [audioPlayer play];
}